# How to print specific columns from file using bash?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have file which context is as follows:

```
               CA Services Status Report

           Component Name               Pid        Status
------------------------------------  -------  --------------
WAAE Web Server (ASD)                   20841  running
WAAE Application Server (ASD)           20281  running
WAAE Scheduler (ASD)                    20486  running
WAAE Agent (WA_AGENT)                   20109  running
CA-wcc-services Server                  22385  running
CA-wcc Server                           24410  running
```

And i wanted to print only Pids on the screen.

I tried using awk and grep but unable to print Pids.

```
cat test | awk '{print $5}'
```

I want to print only the Pid column but unable to print it exactly.

Comment: Are your columns tab separated or just spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following(tested with provided samples).

```
awk 'NF && !/Report/ && !/Status/ && !/^-/{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

OR(as per James sir's comment):

```
awk 'NF&&$(NF-1)~/[0-9]+/{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

Comment: `$(NF-1)` is the best. Maybe reduce it to: `awk 'NF&&$(NF-1)~/[0-9]+/{print $(NF-1)}' file`

Comment: Clever use of `$(NF-1)` ++

Comment: @RavinderSingh Thanks for the your inputs. Please let me know what should we do if need to display only third column i.e. status of services. just like running or not running.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have digits in the pid field, extract the digits:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
20841
20281
...
```

Or use more-than-one space as field-separator after record 4:

```
$ awk -F"  +" 'NR>=5{print $2}' file
20841
20281
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` assuming file has only spaces and digits may appear anywhere in a line:

```
awk '!n && n=index($0, " Pid "){++n} n{s=substr($0, n); sub(/ .*/, "", s); print s}' file
```

```
Pid
-----
20841
20281
20486
20109
22385
24410
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have a fixed layout, just measure where things are:

```
<file tail +5 a.txt | cut -c41-45
```

Start with 5th line, take only characters from 41th to 45th column. Same with AWK (though I find the above more intuitive):

```
awk 'NR>=5 { print substr($0, 41, 5) }' file
```